# Resize height in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I get an example code from Google Map API for resize height "map"

```
 var recalcHeight = function() {
    $("#map").height($(window).height() - 100); //Example
    map && google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); //(*) Don't understand this line
}; 
$(window).resize(recalcHeight);
recalcHeight();
```

Ok, in my php file, I have a div tag: 
1. I don't understand this (*) line above.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know what you question is about because you didn't tag it with *Javascript*, but I think if you knew this, you would have asked what `google.maps.event.trigger(X, Y)` did. Plus, I don't know what this has to do with your `div` tags in your PHP files.

### Google Maps API answer

It's simple to find out what `trigger` does here:

> Triggers the given event. All arguments after eventName are passed as arguments to the listeners.

(From the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=de#event), I found it in no time)

### Javascript answer

If your question is about this whole `&&` construct, I'll explain it to you:

```
map && google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

The `&&` is a logical **AND** with **short-cirquit evaluation** which means:

- If its first argument is *true*, it evaluates the second argument. [Iff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) this is *true* too, it returns *true*.
- If its first argument is *false*, the whole expression can't become *true*, so it **doesn't even evaluate its second argument** and returns *false* immediately.

This mechanism can be (ab)used to change flow control. If the condition (`&&`'s first argument) is false, the second argument doesn't get evaluated, so it's the same as

```
if (map) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
}
```

I don't know how `map` was initialized, but maybe the event trigger is added only if there's a `map` element.

Comment: No problem! If it was helpful, you may want to express your joy with upvoting and/or accepting my answer. :)

Comment: "The && is a logical **OR**" - i think you meant logical **AND**