# Google Maps container doesn't resize properly after animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google maps container, let's say 600px height.

I have a button, resizing (jQuery) the div container arround the map:

```
            $('#add').click(function() {
                 $("#container-map").animate({
                    height: '50%',
                    minHeight: '50%'
                 }, 1500 );
                 google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
            });
```

Now the container and map are of 300px height, but the google maps api thinks it's still 600 pixel, so the center of the map is still at 300 px although it should be at 150 px ( 300 / 2 ).

http://woisteinebank.de/dev2.html#
When you search for a location in the box, it's getting centered.
Hit "Eintragen" and search again, it's not properly centered.

Can you try and verify or even suggest how to fix this flaw?

I tried to use the [usual solution with triggering the `resize` event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523424/resize-height-in-google-map) but it doesn't work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ha ha because you trigger the resize event *before* the animation even starts :-) You have to wait until it ends. For this, use [the 4th argument of .animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) - the `complete` callback which is called after the animation ends:

```
$('#add').click(function() {
     $("#container-map").animate({
        height: '50%',
        minHeight: '50%'
     }, 1500, function () {
          google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
     });
});
```

Comment: _This is just what I was thinking when I looked at '1500' delay..oO_ Thx!

Comment: You are welcome :-) Sorry for the "ha ha" but this is like if you tell me a joke in javascript ;-) (I know programmer's deformation :-))

Comment: @DanFromGermany wow I see you've already fixed it at your web :-)

Comment: np, sure. this is fun project

Comment: @Thomas +1 I have used animate, but only from your answer I came to know executing function after animation completes.  Thanks buddy.