# how do I center a map on my current location html5

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

OK - this one I'm fairly sure is just me working on something way too late in the evening, and  just missing something really simple, so I really apologise if this is something I've missed in research, but I've trawled and trawled...

I have a map that shows many many markers perfectly (a few thousand) that is loaded from a nice xml file, however I really want the map to center on the clients current location. If I hard wire it, all fine, however the dynamic bit is proving waaay too hard. I've looked in the Google docs about it, and looked over here, and even tried reverse engineering some other sites... here is my code running on the body.onload.initialize()

```
var myLat = 35.702069;                     // default location to set centre
var myLng = 139.775327;                    // default location to set centre

var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(myLat,myLng);
//Set up the options for the map
var myOptions =
        {
        zoom: 12,            // Set the zoom level - 15 is good for a suburb
        minZoom: 10,         // Stop zooming too far out
        center: myLatlng,    // ------ centre on the current location ------
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
// pop a marker in the place the map is centred... current location
var myImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('./images/markers/arrow.png');
var marker = createMarker(GetHomeLocationPopup(), myLatlng, myImage);
```

I've tried using things like:

```
var myLat = position.coords.latitude;
var myLng = position.coords.longitude;
```

however these don't look like they are exposed in this context.

Here are my declarations:

```
<body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">
<section id="content" style="width:70%; height:80%">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:80%"></div>
</section>
</body>
```

I'd really not like to use other third-party libraries, and stick a native to the Google code as possible.

Any help gratefully received - and it will mean that I can sleep better :-\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost you need user's location through browsers permission after getting the client's coordinates you can do this,

```
 function success(position) {
    var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
                    map: map,
                    title: "Last Location",
                    icon: "http://i.imgur.com/S1ooXKy.png"
                });

    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude));
    map.setZoom(13);
  };

  function error() {
   console.log("Unable to retrieve your location");
  };

  console.log("Locating…");

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
```

Comment: Hi there @Notável, this helped a HUGE amount, and really I modified it a little for further reuse. I declared `latitude`, and `longitude` outside the function so that the values can be passed around a bit easier, and thn created a position variable `var myPOS = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude)` and then reused myPOS in the map options.

Answer (score 0):

Using the map resize trigger.

```
// Set the center of the map
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)); // google.maps.LatLng object!

// Trigger resize event, telling the API to refresh the view
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

See similiar question: [Google Maps container doesn't resize properly after animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363697/google-maps-container-doesnt-resize-properly-after-animation)

API Links:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at both of the options, and the one from @Notável was very helpful. @DanFromGermany was also interesting and I'll keep that in the back of my mind for a bit later on.

1. I declared the `myLat`, and `myLng` variables as globals (outside this context)
2. I then moved the `position.coords.` into the `success()` function
3. In the `success()` function I added a new variable `myPos` to catch
   the result of `new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude)`

This had the desired effect nicely. Thank you to all who read this question :-)